# Problema al solicitar datos en un arreglo

Tags: java

Estoy empezando con Java y quiero hacer un arreglo y pedir que se llene por teclado pero al ingresar un valor por teclado el programa me da este mensaje:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - constructor Plato in class Vajilla.Plato cannot be applied to given types; required: java.lang.String,java.lang.String,int,int found: no arguments reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length at cosina.Cosina.main(Cosina.java:16) Java Result: 1 BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds).

Si me pudieran ayudar se los agradecería.

```
package Vajilla;

public class Plato {

    private String tamano;
    private String color;
    private int estado;
    private int temperatura;

    public Plato() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    public String getTamano() {
        return tamano;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public int getEstado() {
        return estado;
    }

    public int getTemperatura() {
        return temperatura;
    }



    public void Plato() {
    }

    public Plato(String tamano, String color, int estado, int temperatura) {
        this.tamano = tamano;
        this.color = color;
        this.estado = estado;
        this.temperatura = temperatura;
    }

    public void setTamano(String tamano) {
        this.tamano = tamano;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public void setEstado(int estado) {
        this.estado = estado;
    }

    public void setTemperatura(int temperatura) {
        this.temperatura = temperatura;
    }

    public void TempPlato(){

        if(temperatura>=7){
            System.out.println("Plato caliente");
        }else if(temperatura>4 && temperatura<=6){
            System.out.println("Plato tibio");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Plato frio");
        }

    }
    public void estadoPlato(){
        if(estado>=7){
            System.out.println("En buen estado");
        }else if(estado>5 && estado<7){
            System.out.println("Aceptable");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Malas condiciones");
        }        
    }   

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Plato{" + "tamano=" + tamano + ", color=" + color + ", estado=" + estado + ", temperatura=" + temperatura + '}';
    }

}
```

Esta es la clase **main**

```
package cosina;

import java.util.Scanner;

import Vajilla.Plato;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Cosina {

    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Plato> plat = new ArrayList<>();
        int d;
        do
        {
            Plato p1= new Plato();
            System.out.println("digite el tamano del plato");
            p1.setTamano(sc.next());
            System.out.println("digite el color del plato");
            p1.setColor(sc.next());
            System.out.println("digite el estado del plato de 1 a 10");
            p1.setEstado(sc.nextInt());
            System.out.println("digite la temperatura del plato de 1 a 10");
            p1.setTemperatura(sc.nextInt());
            plat.add(p1);
            System.out.println("desea crear otro plato? presione 1 si o 2 no");
            d=sc.nextInt(); 
        }while(d==1);
        for(Plato obj: plat)
        {
            obj.toString();
         }

    }
}
```

Comment: Al parecer el error te da en el constructor vacio public Plato(){ }, que tiene una excepción de no estar implementado el método (**throw new UnsupportedOperationException**), en esta [publicación](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4861389/3191739), muestra que talvés el IDE que estés usando generó esa excepcion y una opción sería eliminar la excepción ya que ahí tienes un constructor vacío

Comment: Debes implementar el método **public Plato()** o eliminar del método la linea: **throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");**

Comment: Debes eliminar la pregunta [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/296810/error-scanner-en-un-arreglo-en-java) que hiciste, ya que estas preguntando lo mismo, de hecho ahí te dieron la respuesta.

Comment: gracias, ese era el error ya lo arregle.